# redirect to page on a different project in same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a solution with 2 projects.

- - prjLauncher
    -- Launcher.aspx
  - prjTestHarness
    --  TestPage.aspx

TestHarness is the start up project with testpage.aspx at the startup page.

On a button click on testpage i would like to redirect to Launcher.aspx page with a querystring appended.

```
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("/prjLauncher/Launcher.aspx?{0}", ToQueryString(post)));
```

above is the code i am using. I have also referenced Launcher projects reference to TestHarness project.

I get following exception : `The resource cannot be found.`

what am i missing ??

Comment: You can have `Server.mappath` to relate your path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running two separate projects then they will have two separate base urls (or ports) depending on how you are hosting them.

Check the 'web' tab of each projects' properties to find the base addresses.

You should also check that you have selected to start multiple projects enabled and have the 'prjLauncher' project set to 'wait for a request' on startup.

Comment: yes they have different ports. I dont want to hardcode the port address. how can i generalize it ?

Comment: You could put the prjLauncher base url in the prjTestHarness web.config

Comment: it still gives me the same exception after adding the port to url :           Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://localhost:55364/prjLauncher/CCPLauncher.aspx?{0}", ToQueryString(post)));

Comment: Have you checked the things in the final paragraph of my answer?

Comment: yes implemented those changes too.. still the same error.